# How to create pairs in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make connection between agents. I have created 3 breeds of agents: firms, officers and citizens ( each breed has 10 agents), and I need to create pairs. Each pair involves: one firm, one citizen and one officer ( agents are chosen randomly). I also need that all agents will create pairs.

```
breed [ firms firm]
breed [ officers officer]
breed [ citizens citizen]
```

;; then I need to create pairs, and If one agent of the pair is firm then, firm can dicide to bribe or not, if not, firm earns 30, officer earns 0 and citizen earns 10:

```
to go 
 if ticks mod 3 = 0 
  [
   ask turtles 
   [ 
  if breed = firms 
  [ 
    if bribe? = false 
    [ 
       set budget budget + 30
       output-print (word " firms   " budget)
       ask other turtles 
       [ 
         if breed = officers [ set budget budget +   0 
                               output-print (word " officers   " budget)]
         if breed = citizens [ set budget budget +  10 
                               output-print (word " citizens"   budget)]     
            ]
           stop
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
```

;; then go other ticks, where citizen and officer decide to accept bribery or punish for accpeting bribery....

Comment: Hi Erika, an easier way for us to help you, it's provide a short code of your situation...

Comment: on what basis do you want to form pairs? do you want to form all possible pairs, or do you want to repeatedly form a single random pair, or what?

Comment: I want to create all possible pairs and then I want to ask a pair to do the 1. tick, then ask another pair to do 2. tick....

Answer (score 0):

You say “each pair involves: one firm, one citizen and one officer”. I'd call that a triplet, or just a combination rather than a pair; “pair” always means two, never three.

Here's some sample code that forms all possible triplets and then does something approximating your description:

```
ask officers [
  let this-officer self
  ask citizens [
    let this-citizen self
    ask firms [
      if bribe? [
        set budget budget + 30
        ask this-citizen [
          set budget budget + 10
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I wasn't able to understand everything you said about what you're trying to do. But hopefully the above code is close and illustrates the principle of nesting `ask` in order to form all possible combinations.